# "Compile-time hashtable" in C

Tags: c, hashtable, compile-time

I'm implementing a piece of logic in C that goes something like this (for an interpreter):

```
if <input string> in <list of pre-defined constant strings>
  do_a_predefined_action()
else
  do_something_else(<input string>)
```

My first thought was a hashtable, but if the constant strings are known at compile-time it seems a bit wasteful to have to manually initialise a hashtable at runtime.

Other thoughts I had included statically initialising a hashtable structure with known hashes (ick...), then simply using it like normal. Another was a vast, nested `switch` block that would provide `O(log n)` lookup time (not as fast as a hashtable).

What is the best way of achieving lookup for a pre-defined set of strings? What is the solution I haven't seen yet? Elegance would be preferred to speed.

Comment: I would just build the hash table at start-up and be done with it. Later on, if you think start-up time is unacceptable because of this, you can write some kind of pre-processor that builds the hash table up front for inclusion.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: that's the way I'm planning to go if there wasn't a better route. I'm very compulsive about my code and the startup thing seems ugly. Thanks for the input though. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) or [Bob Jenkin's Minimal Perfect Hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html) code to generate a (possibly minimal) [Perfect Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), which will map strings to values, which you can later `switch` on.

Comment: How does this work if the input string is not in the constant list of strings? You still need to check the bytes match in case you've got a false hit.

Comment: @Anonymous: gperf by default does an additional `strcmp` after a match to verify. The other does not (but that shouldn't be too hard to implement).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't be too worried about the cost of initializing a hashtable at program startup. This reeks of premature optimization. That said, ...

Since you do know all the strings, you could look into constructing a *perfect hash* for these strings. There are tools you can use to try many possible hashing algorithms and select the best fit for the data. This would lead to the static-initialization route. Although you've commented "ick" about this strategy. I encourage you to reconsider it if the speed issue is really so very important.

---

I have actually considered this very issue in the context of my postscript interpreter which initializes the `systemdict` hashtable at startup. Another route to consider would be to cache the table in a file. Pseudocode for initializing would then go something like this:

```
check for cached file
if file exists,
    load it.
if file does not exist,
    initialize table manually.
    save table to file.
```

Comment: While @Hasturkun got there first and answered my question, your answer makes a lot of sense and I *am* prematurely optimising. Thanks for the help!